# How to apply a function to a binded textBox with Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

so I'm using the Entity Framework to generate controls according to a certain table in a database, and I use the bindingNavigator as well.
However, there's one string that should be clearly visible on the window, but encrypted in the database (I have the encryption and decryption methods). The problem is : it automatically binds my textBox text to what's stored in the database (the encrypted version), how can I use my decryption function before displaying the text, and encrypt the string when I save ?

I first found a way by changing the text every time I click on a button to change the current record, and other bad improvisation which ended with an awful code, but isn't there a better way with data bindings or something else ? I'll need similar things for others parts of my application, so it'll be a great help to have a simpler -or at least better- way of doing it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [Binding.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse?view=netcore-3.1) and the [Binding.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format?view=netcore-3.1) events to encrypt and decrypt the textbox value.

The Format event allows you to to format the raw data source value (decrypt).  Where-as the Parse event allows you to parse (encrypt) the TextBox value to a value that is stored in the data source.

The following example demonstrates this.  Create a new WinForm project and add a BindingNavigator, TextBox, and DatagridView to the form.  Then modify the form's code to include the following code.  For this example a simple XOR encryption is used.  The DatagridView is used to display the encrypted source values.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Demo();
        }

        private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        public void Demo()
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Encrypted");
            dt.Rows.Add(Encrypt("Fred"));
            dt.Rows.Add(Encrypt("Barney"));
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
            Binding b = textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Encrypted", true);
            b.Parse += EncryptedParse;
            b.Format += EncryptedFormat;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
        }

        private void EncryptedFormat(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = Decrypt((string)(e.Value));
        }

        private void EncryptedParse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = Encrypt((string)(e.Value));
        }

        private string Encrypt(string s)
        {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
                foreach (char c in s)
                {
                    sb.Append((char)(c ^ 2));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }

        private string Decrypt(string s)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                sb.Append((char)(c ^ 2));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
}
```